# Webpack installation webpack@3.5.5 wanted

Tags: node.js, linux, ubuntu, node-modules

Ive been having issues trying to install webpack on both Ubuntu and Debian I keep getting the following error when I do an "npm install -g webpack
". Ive done an update and upgrade, Ive swapped Operating systems between debian and now stuck on Ubuntu. Pretty much confused now.

```
  WARN engine webpack@3.5.5: wanted: {"node":">=4.3.0 <5.0.0 || >=5.10"} (current:                               {"node":"4.2.6","npm":"3.5.2"})
  WARN engine webpack@3.5.5: wanted: {"node":">=4.3.0 <5.0.0 || >=5.10"} (current:                              loadDep:yargs → headers   ▐ ╢██████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
  WARN engine loader-runner@2.3.0: wanted: {"node":">=4.3.0 <5.0.0 || >=5.10"} (cu                              loadDep:yargs → resolveWi ▄ ╢██████████░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░░╟
  WARN engine enhanced-resolve@3.4.1: wanted: {"node":">=4.3.0 <5.0.0 || >=5.10"}                               (current: {"node":"4.2.6","npm":"3.5.2"})
  WARN engine uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6: wanted: {"node":">=4.3.0 <5.0.0 || >=                              /usr/local/bin/webpack -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js

 > uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall /usr/local/lib/node_modules/webpack/                              node_modules/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
 > node lib/post_install.js

 sh: 1: node: not found
 /usr/local/lib
 └── (empty)

 npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /webpack/chokidar/fsevents                              :
 npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fseve                              nts@1.1.2
 npm ERR! Linux 2.6.32-042stab123.9
 npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "webpack"
 npm ERR! node v4.2.6
 npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
 npm ERR! file sh
 npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
 npm ERR! errno ENOENT
 npm ERR! syscall spawn

 npm ERR! uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall: `node    lib/post_install.js`
 npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
 npm ERR!
 npm ERR! Failed at the uglifyjs-webpack-plugin@0.4.6 postinstall script   'node li                              b/post_install.js'.
 npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm    installed.
 npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the uglifyjs-  webpack-plug                              in package,
 npm ERR! not with npm itself.
 npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
 npm ERR!     node lib/post_install.js
 npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
 npm ERR!     npm bugs uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
 npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
 npm ERR!     npm owner ls uglifyjs-webpack-plugin
 npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

 npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
 npm ERR!     /root/npm-debug.log
 npm ERR! code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using node version 4.2.6 which is under 4.3.
Webpack need version of node over 4.3

Update your node version if possible.

```
$ sudo apt-get install curl
$ curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash –
$ sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

or use `n` library of npm.